# iterator to a vector of vector of int

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, dereference

I have an error in the following code where I want to print the first element in each sub-vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> logs{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}};
for (auto beg = logs.begin(); beg != logs.end(); beg++) {
    cout << *beg[0] << endl;
}
```

the error is from `cout << *beg[0]...`:

```
Indirection requires pointer operand ('std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>' invalid)
```

So my question is: the dreference of the iterator should a sub-vector in the vector "logs", so I use subscript to access the first element of it. Why there's a `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>` object? Where does the `std::allocator<int>` come from? How can I access the elements in the sub-vectors?

Comment: Replace it with `cout << (*beg)[0] << endl;`

Comment: Or with `cout << beg->at(0) << endl;`, which does bounds checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem**(cause of the mentioned error) is that due to [**operator precedence**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the expression `*beg[0]` is grouped as(or equivalent to):

```
*(beg[0])
```

which can't work because `beg` is an iterator and has no `[]` operator. This is because the operator `[]` has higher precedence than operator `*`.

To solve this replace `cout << *beg[0] << endl;` with:

```
cout << (*beg)[0] << endl;  //or use beg->at(0)
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/r_msgYNip)